# GCM server jar and GCM with GWT

Tags: gwt, google-cloud-messaging

Hi am new bee to the GCM and GWT and i was worndering from where do i get the jar for the gcm-server implementation,i was literally not able to find the jar for the download.
Can anyone please guide me from where do i get the gcm-server.jar for my appengine server.

And also how do i go ahead with the GWT push implementation to android using GCM.

[link for the GCM-android](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html)

i have found this link but i was not sure if this page had any source for the gcm-server jar for download.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the gwt-server.jar.
When we install the Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library from extras on eclipse, in the android root directory/extras directory gcm directory will be created and insite that we have another directory dist/gcm-server inside which we can get gcm-server.jar and also some really helpful demo for google appengine with gcm.

Comment: Abhisek This is right way.But when I click how it is downvoted by mistakelately.How can I up vote this.

Answer (score 2):

Please check following url.

https://github.com/slorber/gcm-server-repository/tree/master/deployer

you get Gcm-server.jar file

And other full Detail get from following url.

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

Comment: You get Full android DemoExample from https://github.com/olegflo/simple-android-gcm-example